# Is "with" or "by" the correct word in the phrase: Replaced ________ a new printer

Tags: grammaticality

English is my second language. Which of the following is correct?

> 1. Replaced with a new printer.
> 2. Replaced by a new printer.

Answer (score 1):

Either preposition is fine, and they mean exactly the same. But ***by*** is currently more common...

[image]

---

Note that things change significantly if you include an *object* after the verb...

[image]

But that change only really took off a few decades ago, and it's got nothing to do with "grammar" as such - it's just an idiomatic preference that happens to have become widespread. But my guess is that within a few more decades, ***with*** will probably be more common in *all* contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Fred replaced the printer with a new one. 
The printer was replaced by a new one, by Fred.

Comment: I don't actually disagree with the point I assume you're making, but the person doing the replacing is missing from your second example. And lets face it, most of us would have misgivings about *"The printer was replaced by a new one **by me**"*, which would be the more complete version of your first sentence re-cast into the passive.

Comment: Granted; I'll edit.

Answer (score -2):

*with* is the correct word. *by* is usually used to refer to whoever performed the replacement, e.g. "Replaced by the technician with a new printer". It can also be used to introduce a process, e.g. "Replaced by getting a new printer".